# LUA Error - attempt to index field 'database' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

Logs --

```
16:12:35 Lua Error: [ERROR] addons/tttdamagelogs-master/lua/rdm_manager/sv_rdm_manager.lua:472: attempt to index field 'database' (a nil value)
```

Code which starts at line 471 --

```
local encoded = util.TableToJSON(tbl)
local update = Damagelog.database:query("UPDATE damagelog_previousreports SET report = "..sql.SQLStr(encoded).." WHERE _index = "..tbl.index..";")

update:start()
```

---

I am wondering why I am receiving the error as stated above, referencing to line 472? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because `Damagelog` does not contain a key named `database`. Most likely cause is a typo, for example perhaps it should be `damagelog` or  `DamageLog` (Lua names are case sensitive).